# Sdcard Awkward Bug

Tags: android, sd-card

I'm currently developing an app with some friends and we were testing with our android cells and everything worked fine.
We tested with another friend of ours android today and suddenly we found a bug.
Our friend has a memory card and because of that he has sdcard0 and sdcard1 and the bug shows because the app is on sdcard0 and it searches on sdcard1.
Is there any way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't hardcode the path to the sdcard.

You have to use the [external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) api instead:

```
public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
    // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory not created");
    }
    return file;
}
```

The example above is for an album photo, but the getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() method should work equally well in case you're dealing with mp3s or videos.